# Why does my linked list only contain one node even though I added more than one?

Tags: c, linked-list

I'm trying to make a simple linked list programming.
This is my code
I expected the output to have 4 lines

Tugi 1

Bill 2

Sweet 3

Miharu 4

but the output is Tugi 1 only.
What's wrong with my code ?

I am asked to do another assignment about linked list, but my professor didn't explain it well so I'm just trying to make a simple programming to test linked list.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
typedef struct _member{
    char name[20];
    int number;
    struct _member* next; //pointer to the next structure
}
MEMBER;

void AddMember(MEMBER* start, char* namae, int num);

MEMBER* NewMember(char* namae, int num);
    //void FreeLink(MEMBER* start);
void PrintMember(MEMBER* start);

int main(){
    static int serialNum=1;
    MEMBER* start = NewMember("Tugi", serialNum++);
    AddMember(start, "Bill", serialNum++);
    AddMember(start, "Sweet", serialNum++);
    AddMember(start, "Miharu", serialNum++);
    PrintMember(start);
    free(start);
    return 0;
}

MEMBER* NewMember(char* namae, int num){
    MEMBER* this;
    this = (MEMBER*)malloc(sizeof(MEMBER)); //allocate the memory
    strcpy(this->name, namae); //copy the name
    this->number = num;
    this->next = NULL; //The next is NULL
    return(this);
}
void AddMember(MEMBER* start, char* namae, int num){
    MEMBER* p=start;
    while(p!=NULL) p = p->next;
    p = (MEMBER*)malloc(sizeof(MEMBER));
    strcpy(p->name, namae);
    p->number = num;
    p->next = NULL;
}
void PrintMember(MEMBER* start)
{
    MEMBER* p;
    for(p=start; p!=NULL; p=p->next){
        printf("%s %d\n", p->name, p->number);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your AddMember function you do not modify the last element in the list to point to the new element so the linked list is never created

instead modify the last element before adding the new

also make sure you include stdlib.h for malloc since you should not cast malloc()

```
void AddMember(MEMBER* start, char* namae, int num)
{
  MEMBER* p=start;
  MEMBER* q=NULL;
  while(p!=NULL) 
  {
    q = p; 
    p = p->next;
  }
  p = malloc(sizeof(MEMBER));
  strcpy(p->name, namae);
  p->number = num;
  p->next = NULL;
  if ( q != NULL )
  {
    q->next = p;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Your add function never sets the last pointer in your chain to the new node being allocated. it only acquires its value (which is NULL), then creates a new node, storing its address in a local pointer `p`. The newly allocated node is then filled with data, but is still detached from the original list.

The are a multitude of ways to do this correctly. I prefer the following simply because it allows you to use `AddMember` for *all* additions, not having to special-case the first addition like you currently do. It utilizes a pointer-to-pointer approach:

```
void AddMember(MEMBER** start, char const* name, int num)
{
    // loop until the pointer who's address is stored in
    //  the start parameter is NULL.
    while (*start)
        start = &(*start)->next;

    // start now contains the address of the last pointer
    //  in our linked list. allocate a new node, saving the
    //  address in that pointer.
    *start = NewMember(name, num);
}
```

You also need a mechanism for freeing the entire list; not just the first node. `free()` won't cut it. Again, utilizing a pointer-to-pointer:

```
void FreeMembers(MEMBER** start)
{
    while (*start)
    {
        MEMBER *tmp = *start;
        *start = tmp->next;
        free(tmp);
    }
}
```

Invoked in your `main()` like this:

```
int main()
{
    static int serialNum=1;
    MEMBER* start = NULL; // Note: MUST be NULL on inception.

    AddMember(&start, "Tugi", serialNum++);
    AddMember(&start, "Bill", serialNum++);
    AddMember(&start, "Sweet", serialNum++);
    AddMember(&start, "Miharu", serialNum++);

    PrintMember(start);

    FreeMembers(&start);

    return 0;
}
```

Best of luck.

Answer (score 0):

Because you're overriding the last link, instead of setting it's next chain.

So, on the first add, you'll get `Tugi`, and then replace it with the follow one. you need to set the `p->next` to be the newly created link.

Once you find the last link (`p`), create a new one (`new_p`), and then at the end do: `p->next = new_p;` (which is actually adding the new link to the end).